# Azure AD B2C with Graph API - how to get/set user's email?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I add users to Azure AD B2C with Graph API but I don't get it how to store users' email (the primary one). Which field **[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity)** is the user's primary email address?

As I read here on SO there's no way to populate values in **Authentication contact info**. It this correct?

Comment: read here is missing a link.  FYI.

Comment: I see the link right there... let me add another one

Comment: do you see the link now?

Comment: No, I do not.  "As I read here on SO there's no way" does not have a link.  You can use the preview feature that will show you how it will look after you post your question.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45344259/unable-to-retrieve-user-email-from-azure-ad-b2c-using-graphapi/45501610#45501610

Comment: RE: Authentication contact info - correct, there's no way to populate that at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I do it:

```cs
public async Task<AdUser> GetUserByObjectId(Guid objectId)
{
    string userJson = await SendGraphGetRequest("/users/" + objectId, null);
    JObject jUser = JObject.Parse(userJson);
    return new AdUser(jUser);
}

internal AdUser(JObject jUser)
{
    AccountEnabled = jUser["accountEnabled"].Value<bool>();
    CompanyName = jUser["companyName"].Value<string>();
    Department = jUser["department"].Value<string>();
    DisplayName = jUser["displayName"].Value<string>();
    FirstName = jUser["givenName"].Value<string>();
    JobTitle = jUser["jobTitle"].Value<string>();
    LastName = jUser["surname"].Value<string>();
    MailNickname = jUser["mailNickname"].Value<string>();
    Mobile = jUser["mobile"].Value<string>();
    ObjectId = new Guid(jUser["objectId"].Value<string>());

    List<string> mailList = new List<string>(jUser["otherMails"].Count());
    mailList.AddRange(jUser["otherMails"].Select(mail => mail.Value<string>()));
    OtherMails = mailList.AsReadOnly();

    Phone = jUser["telephoneNumber"].Value<string>();

    List<(string type, string value)> signInNames = jUser["signInNames"].Select(jToken => (jToken["type"].Value<string>(), jToken["value"].Value<string>())).ToList();
    SignInNames = signInNames.AsReadOnly();

    UserPrincipalName = jUser["userPrincipalName"].Value<string>();
    UserType = jUser["userType"].Value<string>();
}
```

and here's the Email property of the AdUser:

```cs
public string Email
{
    get
    {
        if (SignInNames.Count > 0 && SignInNames[0].type == "emailAddress")
            return SignInNames[0].value;
        if (OtherMails.Count > 0)
            return OtherMails[0];
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Don't know where to get user Email");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a PATCH request to the users endpoint

```
{baseurl}/{tenantId}/users?api-version={apiVersion}
```

Don't forget you access token in the auth header:

```
Authorization: Bearer {accessToken}
```

Here's an example model (Java) with methods for calculating and setting the sign-in email on a user object:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class GraphApiUserExample{

    @JsonProperty("objectId")
    private String id;

    private Boolean accountEnabled;

    private PasswordProfile PasswordProfile;

    private List<SignInName> signInNames;

    private String surname;

    private String displayName;

    private String givenName;

    @JsonProperty("userPrincipalName")
    private String userPrincipalName;

    public String getId(){

        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final String id){

        this.id = id;
    }

    public Boolean getAccountEnabled(){

        return accountEnabled;
    }

    public void setAccountEnabled(final Boolean accountEnabled){

        this.accountEnabled = accountEnabled;
    }

    public PasswordProfile getPasswordProfile(){

        return passwordProfile;
    }

    public void setPasswordProfile(final PasswordProfile passwordProfile){

        this.passwordProfile = passwordProfile;
    }

    public List<SignInName> getSignInNames(){

        return signInNames;
    }

    public void setSignInNames(final List<SignInName> signInNames){

        this.signInNames = signInNames;
    }

    public String getSurname(){

        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(final String surname){

        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getDisplayName(){

        return displayName;
    }

    public void setDisplayName(final String displayName){

        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public String getGivenName(){

        return givenName;
    }

    public void setGivenName(final String givenName){

        this.givenName = givenName;
    }

    public String getUserPrincipalName(){

        return userPrincipalName;
    }

    public void setUserPrincipalName(final String userPrincipalName){

        this.userPrincipalName = userPrincipalName;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public String getSignInEmail(){

        String email = "";
        if(signInNames != null){
            for(SignInName signInName : signInNames){
                if(signInName.getType().equals("emailAddress")){
                    email = signInName.getValue();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return email;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public void setSignInEmail(String signInEmail){

        if(signInNames == null){
            signInNames = new ArrayList<>();
            signInNames.add(new SignInName("emailAddress", signInEmail));
            return;
        }

        for(SignInName signInName : signInNames){
            if(signInName.getType().equals("emailAddress")){
                signInName.setValue(signInEmail);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SignInName:

```
public class SignInName {//userName or emailAddress

    private String
        type,
        value;

    public String getType(){

        return type;
    }

    public void setType(final String type){

        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getValue(){

        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(final String value){

        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

PasswordProfile:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class PasswordProfile {

    private String password;

    private Boolean forceChangePasswordNextLogin;

    public String getPassword(){

        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(final String password){

        this.password = password;
    }

    public Boolean getForceChangePasswordNextLogin(){

        return forceChangePasswordNextLogin;
    }

    public void setForceChangePasswordNextLogin(final Boolean forceChangePasswordNextLogin){

        this.forceChangePasswordNextLogin = forceChangePasswordNextLogin;
    }
}
```