# Azure AD B2C User Import: Can't Associate Email w/ Username

Tags: azure, email, import, azure-ad-b2c

Hi hopefully someone can help.

I'm importing users into Azure B2C using the Azure AD Graph and have to use the username sign in approach.  We can import the users but we cannot set the `mail` field because we get an error:

> read-only

When testing the self-service reset password functionality, we get:

> AADB2C90161:+A+self-asserted+send+response+has+failed+with+reason+'Internal+Server+Error'

I believe this is because when resetting the password you have to supply an email address that you validate with a code.

How do we associate the email with the account when we cannot import the email because the mail field is read-only?  Has anyone else had this issue?  Any workarounds?

Comment: Related SO Post: [Unable to retrieve user email from Azure AD B2C using GraphAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45344259/unable-to-retrieve-user-email-from-azure-ad-b2c-using-graphapi/45501610#45501610)

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to use the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com) and manually set it.  This will allow the `Password Reset Policy` to work.  This is obviously won't scale very well.

`B2C Tenant -> Users and Groups -> All Users -> Open the User -> Set the authenticated email address`

[image: update authenticated email address]

Comment: Thanks, Nice option but unfortunately we have over 60,000 users to import.

Comment: @RMcfarlane yeah that option is not going to work for that!  There has to be another workaround here...

Comment: So today I wrote a console app that basically fires up the browser using the chrome driver and basically enters everything in and does the whole sign up, it does about 10 a minute, I’m just going to get a few machines to run it and import that way, very hacky but it should get the job done for now.

Comment: Haha, love the tenacity!  You should provide that as an answer to ur question.

Comment: Ever get the feeling that the people who build these products never actually have to use them?  :-(