# Use microsoft graph to authentication contact info to get the email

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

How do you get the authentication contact info from azure ad b2c with the microsoft graph, I am looking to retrieve the email address.

I checked the documentation on Microsoft Graph API and could find no mention of how to get the Authentication Contact Info besides using PowerShell (learn.microsoft.com/en-za/azure/active-directory/authentication/…)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45808409/1531971 https://stackoverflow.com/q/45344259/1531971 and others are good starts, and then you can tell us why those don't apply.

Comment: I did do a search and none of the answers answered my question, I am looking to use Microsoft Graph API to get the Authentication Contact Info Email, not the normal mail tag.

Comment: I checked the documentation on Microsoft Graph API and could find no mention of how to get the Authentication Contact Info besides using PowerShell (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-za/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-sspr-authenticationdata#set-and-read-authentication-data-using-powershell)

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned it seems that there is no microsoft Graph API could get the authentication Contact Info Email.

But we could get that information with following API, I capture it with browser. It seems a litte hack.

```
Get https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api/UserDetails/{userId}
```

About how to get the access token, please refer to this [blog](http://devchat.live/en/2018/01/10/how-to-call-rest-apis-on-azure-portal/).

**Note:** I don't find this API in the Azure official document. Please don't use it for product, you could use it for test.

[image]

Comment: I actually need to use it for a product, the only way I saw you can get this information is to use powershell but I would want to use the graph api rather

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this article](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/), there are still some gaps between the **Microsoft Graph API** and the older **Azure AD Graph API**, but seems neither will fully retrieve what's required.

As of now, the following with get the `Alternate Email` field *only* from the "Authentication contact info" section using the **Azure AD Graph API**;

### Register the Application in Azure AD

In the Azure Active Directory instance;

- [Register](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-add-azure-ad-app#adding-an-application) a new application (`client_id`)
- Grant **"Read all users' full profiles"** [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference?view=graph-rest-1.0) to **Windows Azure Active Directory**
- Create a private key (`client_secret`) for the application

### Authentication Flow

Reference: [Service to Service Calls Using Client Credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/dn645543%28v%3dazure.100%29)

**Retrieve an access token**

*Request*

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>/oauth2/token
```

*Payload*

```
{
  "client_id": "<client_id>",
  "client_secret": "<client_secret>",
  "resource": "https://graph.windows.net",
  "grant_type": "client_credentials"
}
```

### User Authentication Contact Info

Reference: [Basic operations on users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#basic-operations-on-users--)

**Get user**

*Request*

```
GET https://graph.windows.net/<tenant_id>/users/<user_id>?api-version=1.6
```

*Headers*

```
{
  "Authorization": "Bearer <access_token>"
}
```

*Response*

```
{
    ...
    "otherMails": ["<Alternate Email>"],
    ...
}
```